# how to create a simple website template using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, web

Can someone please give me a simple example of html and css that I need to have to create something like this picture using bootstrap?
[website template like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMzun.png)

I searched the web but cannot find a simple example!
(for bootstrap v3.3.7 in asp.net mvc project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code for You, enjoy!

```
<div class="row">
HEADER
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
  SIDEBAR
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    content1
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
    content2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
FOOTER
</div>
```

Comment: should I use those lines of code inside the <body> tags?

Comment: there is a problem, I used those lines of code inside body tags and the problem is that in firefox cannot see the h in header and only see half of e of header, what I want to say is that those are not inside the viewport! why?

Comment: I found the why myself, you have to put them inside column classes like so:   <div class="col-md-4">
  Header
  </div>

Answer (score 0):

This is the complete and corrected answer:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4"> HEADER </div>

</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
  SIDEBAR
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    content1
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
    content2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4"> FOOTER </div>
</div>
```